# Laravel: Not picking up __invoke method?

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to use invokable controllers, but it seems to fail to find the __invoke method?

```
Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\MainController].
```

It seems to be returning true on:

```
if (! method_exists($action, '__invoke')) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException("Invalid route action: [{$action}].");
}
```

Routes:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', \App\Http\Controllers\MainController::class);
```

MainController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        dd('main');
    }
}
```

Comment: It's picking it up as `App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\MainController` under the hood.  I have no idea why.

Comment: the namespace of the controller is wrong try to use this `App\Http\Controllers\MainController::class` or this `"MainController"` in route declaration

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Laravel by default assumes that your controllers will be located at `App\Http\Controllers\`. So when you're adding the full path to your controller, Laravel will check it there, at `App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\MainController`.

To solve it simply remove the namespace when you're registering the route, and register it like this:

```
Route::get('/', MainController::class);
```

Alternatively, you can stop this behavior by removing `->namespace($this->namespace)` from  `mapWebRoutes()` method on `RouteServiceProvider` class, which is located at `App\Providers` folder. Then you can register your routes like this:

```
Route::get('/', \App\Http\Controllers\MainController::class);
```

Comment: Is there a way to stop PHP storm and other IDEs complaining `Undefined class`? Clicking on the class name to go to the definition is useless right now.

Comment: @notatroll I'm not PHPStorm user, but I think people are using [Laravel IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) to solve this issue.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can use:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\MainController;

Route::get('/', [MainController::class, '__invoke']);
```

In this case, the `namespace` provided in `RouteServiceProvider` won't be taken into account.
The advantage of this is that now your IDE will be able to reference the class usage and you can navigate by clicking on it.

Comment: In Laravel 8 world, this seems to be the preferred way.

Answer (score 4):

The best answer that works for everyone is laravel documentation.

just use this at the top of your route(web.php) if (websiteController is the name of your controller)

```
use App\Http\Controllers\WebsiteController;
```

and define your route like this for your index page

```
Route::get('/', [WebsiteController::class, 'index']);
```

take note of the

```
[             ]
```

Comment: This is not the case for a single action controller. No method name is needed, no array required for the second method parameter. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#single-action-controllers

Answer (score 1):

**Always Declare/Use in Top**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\backend\DashboardController;
```

**Then Use this way**

```
   Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
```

**If have Auth and Use Group**

```
 Route::middleware([
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),
    'verified'
])->group(function () {

    Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the crontoller with argument "--invokable"

```
php artisan make:controller YourController --invokable
```

Answer (score -2):

Change your route to:

```
Route::get('/', "MainController");
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case I forget to set @action, so change your code from:

```
Route::get('admin/orders', 'Admin\OrderController')->name('admin.orders');
```

to:

```
Route::get('admin/orders', 'Admin\OrderController@index')->name('admin.orders');
```

Answer (score -2):

you have mentioned get link, but you have not declared which method it should call.

```
Route::get('/', \App\Http\Controllers\MainController::class);// if you are importing lass like this you have to use resource instead of get.
```

you can solve this issue by two ways,

1. first way,

`Route::get('/', '\App\Http\Controllers\MainController@index');` // you have to mention your method which you have mentioned in controller

2. another way is,

   ```
   Route::resource('/', \App\Http\Controllers\MainController::class);
   ```

In, 2nd method laravel will automatically find which request and where should redirect.2nd option is prefered if you are using multiple method for the same route.

Comment: A single action controller doesn't need a method. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#single-action-controllers

Answer (score -2):

Route::resource('/', \App\Http\Controllers\MainController::class);

Use method 'resource'

Comment: There was no suggestion in the question that the user wanted to create resource routes.